# Typescript classes extends Tuple

Tags: typescript, inheritance, tuples

I'm looking for a way to extend a Tuple in TypeScript.

In C#, you can easily do:

```
public class extends String { ... }
```

In TypeScript, I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
export class Field extends [string, string] { ... }
```

Any ideas ?

*Note: My goal is naming each tuple member.*

Answer (score 4):

If you need to name your tuple members you might be better off with an interface.

If you really want to derive the tuple, you can do it, but you will need a tuple constructor to act as the base class. Tuples at runtime are just arrays in javascript so what we really want is  typed alias for the `Array` constructor, so your are really inheriting `Array`:

```
const tupleConstructor: new (...p: [string, string]) => [string, string] = Array as any;
class Field extends tupleConstructor{ 
  constructor(...p: [string, string]) {
    super(...p);
    (this as any).__proto__ = Field.prototype; // fix for inheriting arrays
  }
  get firstName() { return this[0]; }
  get lastName() { return this[1];}
}

let a = new Field("1", "1");
let [a0, a1] = a;
console.log(`0: ${a0}`);
console.log(`1: ${a1}`);

let { firstName, lastName} = a;
console.log(`firstName: ${firstName}`);
console.log(`lastName: ${lastName}`);
```

Comment: Nice! Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

If you goal is just to name the tuples...

With typescript > 4.0 (in Beta at time of writing this), you can now name tuples:

```
type MyNamedTuple = [foo: string, bar: string];
```

This is helpful to get code complete when using `...args` with tuple generics

[image]